# Display lock screen message in kde

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen

I would like to display a message such as **will be back in 10 minutes** when you lock your screen in kde? I could not find an option in the system settings.  How do you display a message when you lock your screen in kde?

I just want the ability to type my message which would get displayed on your lock your screen. The lock screen should show what it displays by default plus my message that I typed.

Comment: Display a message that says or do what?

Comment: KDE 4.2 Beta 1 Release Announcement: **New Plasma applets include applets for leaving messages on a locked screen**. So install the applet?

Answer (score 0):

**There are many ways...**

What is your KDE version ?
These options are available with the KDE 4.11 - http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.11.1

KDE system settings > Display and Monitor > Screen Locker

[image]

The locker screen is as any KDE plasma desktop. It can have own widgets and wallpaper. Desktop Widgets > Configure -> Left click the toolbox on the locker desktop or right click the locker desktop.

[image]

1) As the 'Rinzwind' pointed you could use the plasma notes.

[image]

2) or add a sign wallpaper to the locker screen

[image]

3) or use the screen saver banner option

[image]